# Do pushcli() and popcli() in the spinlock of XV6 need atomic?

Tags: c, atomic, spinlock, xv6

As learning XV6's spinlock,I thought a problem and don't find answer in google.
In [spinlock](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/master/spinlock.c), `pushcli()` and `popcli()` used to insure interrupt handler run currently:

```
void pushcli(void)
{
  int eflags;

  eflags = readeflags();
  cli();
  if (mycpu()->ncli == 0)
    mycpu()->intena = eflags & FL_IF;
  mycpu()->ncli += 1;
}

void popcli(void)
{
  if (readeflags() & FL_IF)
    panic("popcli - interruptible");
  if (--mycpu()->ncli < 0)
    panic("popcli");
  if (mycpu()->ncli == 0 && mycpu()->intena)
    sti();
}
```

However, the spinlock is used to dure with threads and func in it like `xchg()` should be atomic,but codes in `pushcli()` and `popcli` like `mycpu()->ncli += 1;` are not atomic , which might cause incorrect result of ncli and intena.So why we can use nonatomic operations in `pushcli()`?If we shouldn't, what can we do to correct it to safe？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

- `mycpu()->ncli` is local to each CPU
- `lk->locked` is shared between all CPUs

---

No `pushcli` and `popcli` don't need be atomic because they can't be preempted.

We have two different context here:

1. The access to `spinlock->locked` (`lk->locked`) member

   ```
   // The xchg is atomic.
   while(xchg(&lk->locked, 1) != 0)
     ;
   ```
2. And the enabling/disable of interruption: `cli()`/`sti()`

In the first case, the variable is stored in memory, any cpu could want to access the lock at any time, the atomic instruction is need here: only one cpu can have access to it.

In the second case, we are in the kernel code of a cpu: the code executed is local to given processor and once `cli` is called the **cpu can't interrupt (so can't be preempted)** until `sti` is called.

Since the cpu deals with a variable that is private to it `mycpu()->ncli;`, no atomicity is needed here.

---

To be exact, `mycpu()` read a shared array `cpus[]`,  and by design return the `cpu` structure referring to the CPU that executed the function. Note that `mycpy()` require interrupt to be disabled to execute (if not, you got a kernal panic).

Comment: Of course, the `*mycpu()` object is also stored in memory, and could in principle be accessed concurrently by another core, but presumably the code is designed so that no other core ever tries to do so.

Comment: @NateEldredge you're right, by design, `mycpu()` return the cpu structure for the cpu executing the function, accessing the `cpus[NCPU]` array.